# network_security_config isn't working on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ssl-certificate

I am setting SSL pinning config for my app, I am using `network_security_config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config>
<domain includeSubdomains="true">mydomain.com</domain>
<pin-set expiration="2024-01-01">
<pin digest="SHA-256">KeyValue</pin>
</pin-set>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

This my `androidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.unity3d.player"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@XML/network_security_config" tools:targetApi="n">
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
android:theme="@StyLe/UnityThemeSelector">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

`network_security_config` on my android isn’t work, I tried to set pin digest values with wrong value but API part still pass (if `network_security_config` is work, API part will fail and get SSL error).

On iOS, I tested with SSL pinning and everything works fine, when I set correct key SSL pinning → API part works well and when I set wrong key SSL pinning → API part get SSL error (This proves that the SSL server is correct).
I don’t know what problem cause `network_security_config` on Android to not work.

Comment: What HTTP client als TLS  Implementation have you configured in your project? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=windows